# lAdding files to a two column listbox

Tags: vba

I am trying to add files to a list box in the same way as they are added when files are attached to an email, in two columns but able to address each file uniquely.
I am using Access VBA and do not know if it is possible.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the indices of the items in the listBox to the files using a separate array/collection/dictionary. Then, when an item is selected, you can use the item's index to get the link

I just tried this below, works perfectly.
Userform Code:

```
Private d As Dictionary

Private Sub userform_initialize()
    Set d = New Dictionary

    'populate list box, and add items to dictionary
    For i = 1 To 3
        With ListBox1
            d.Add .ListCount, "Link" & i
            .AddItem 0
            .List(.ListCount - 1) = "Hello World"
        End With
    Next
End Sub

'update label1's value based of listbox's selected item
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    With ListBox1
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Label1.Caption = d.Item(.ListIndex)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And the userform looked like this: (listbox named ListBox1, and label named Label1):
[image]

Example:
[image]

If you have problems using the dictionary object, you need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". But really any collection-type can replace the dictionary in this case (an array/Collection)