# Creating a string picker dialog from a collection in vba via built in dialog?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, dialog, built-in

(Questions with an answer of NO are still useful; they're just not the solution to the problem.  Answers say, no, there is no built-in, you have to implement the dialog for yourself...)

In VBA, (ms-word, or ms-excel, but seems like a generic operation) is there any way to simply a provide a collection to a built in dialog in order to prompt the user to select a value from a list of values?

I can't believe there's not a built in method to do this, it seems like a such a generic operation that could be coded once and everybody would re-use it.  I can certainly hand code it, but why bother if it's already in the vba libraries someplace.

I've searched for a solution, but it does appear that the standard answer is to [hand code it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435931/ladding-files-to-a-two-column-listbox/24436376#24436376).

Comment: I think the reason this kind of thing is not a common piece of reference code is that you're talking about (a) a form, including properties and controls (b) some code driving the form (c) a public module function or a class that hides the complexity. Sharing those things together in some easy copy-paste format would be rather difficult.

Comment: @Blackhawk I was hoping it would be a Microsoft standard VBA library for a picker dialog.  But I do see that there are no general dialogs available; all the pre-canned dialogs for vba seem to be coded for Excel or Word functionality and exposed to VBA via Application.Dialogs(wdDialogInsertField).Show (for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

My aproach would be to create a Form, add a ListBox, Ok, Cancel and the ShowModal property.
To use it first set the ListBox RowSource according to what you need:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196460.aspx

Then make it visible, manage Ok/Cancel and then use the ItemsSelect property (multiselect is possible): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823015.aspx

Comment: Sure, that's the hand coded method.  It just seems like that should EXIST in MS code because it's such an elementary implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, no such thing.

Hand-code it, and keep it as part of your VBA "toolbox" - make yourself an add-in that other VBA projects can reference, so you can reuse the code without having to rewrite it every time.

Then export the code modules from your host document, upload them to a GitHub repository, and share your solution with the world so the next person looking for it doesn't need to implement it from scratch again.

The VBA standard library is rather limited, and beyond `MsgBox` there isn't much available in terms of built-in UI. That's just how it is.

Comment: Gaah.  What craziness.  Thanks much.  The investment in something globally useful is more than "just make it work" but maybe the useful solution will evolve over time.

Comment: @BenPen you might also want to consider writing a COM-visible type library in C# or VB.NET, and work off arrays instead of collections (easier marshaling I guess), for a more "universal" solution. Heck, you could even make it a cutting-edge WPF UI and reimplement the `MsgBox` and `InputBox` functions, too.

Comment: I was actually looking to make use of polymorphism.  Collections have an interator with GetFirst and GetNext, right?   Is it just wishful thinking that there's uniformity of interface for accessing a list of x in word or excel? (range of cells, set of sentences, set of paragraphs, array, etc)  If you just throw a collection at the popup and maybe a sort order option: ascending, decending or default (randomish in non-sequential collections such as a hash).  It would be super easy to use.  If you cared a lot about order, you just create an array to pass in, if not, use the defaults.

Comment: *Collections have an interator with GetFirst and GetNext, right?* not quite. Iteratable types have a hidden `_NewEnum` member with `UserMemId` flag set to `-4`, that returns an `IUnknown`. There's no "framework" in VBA, the `Collection` class doesn't "implement" some `IEnumerable` interface that you can use, so you would have to make your parameter a `Variant` and then determine if that's an array, or else try to iterate it with `For Each` - seems you're expecting VBA to be strongly typed as a .NET language. It's not. It's from last century.

Comment: Ah.  And it never caught up...  That would be why such a window doesn't exist: no uniformity of access interface between all storage methods.   Sometimes the price of backwards compatibility back to the dawn of time is quite high...  This would have been an easy thing to fix over time, if not for that...  Make the object model go a bit deeper, and voila.  Thanks @mat'smug.

Comment: As a non-com object, could I not declare the build function as Build(list as object), pass in any object that is a collection that works with foreach and use foreach to get the strings in the collection?   I realize that for COM, you'd have to standardize on variant, and it gets dicey, but a code module/add-in should be able to do this, no?

Comment: VBA objects *are* COM obejcts. But yeah, you could pass anything that works with `For Each` and work with that - but I'd go with `Variant` instead of `Object`; `Object` would not work with arrays, `Variant` would. Although, it's debatable whether iterating arrays with `For Each` is a good idea.